# Switch off auto data type identification in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

apologies in advance if this question was previously raised, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Does anyone know if there is a way to turn off or ideally set auto data type identification to "Short Text"? I believe MS Access looks at the first 24 rows and applies data type for the table. In my case first 24 (in fact 1000s ) of first column data might be a Number but I need to be Short Text as some of the numbers are alphanumeric.

So I'm importing (linking) .CSV file first to a temp table then passing data to another table via ODBC connection. So is there a way to make sure that in temp table "tblrsSLPARENTTEMP" data type will always be set as "Short Text"?

```
Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next: db.TableDefs.Delete "tblrsSLPARENTTEMP": On Error GoTo 0
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblrsSLPARENTTEMP", _
FileName:=strPathFile, HasFieldNames:=True
db.TableDefs.Refresh
```

Note:

1. Columns in .CSV file might change places, so one day data in column A could be in column B the next day.
2. I need to know column names, so `HasFieldNames:=False` wouldn't be an option

Comment: I did, but the problem is that the column layout might change so it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to be useful for anyone, but couldn't find a solution in Access, so what I did that worked was:

1. Created a VBA in Excel to insert 50 lines of alphanumeric text in CSV file and save it
2. Import into Access DB.

Is created linked DB with a short text data type. Not the cleanest solution but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

After importing the data to access,then you can change the field type by is name like

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE YourTableName ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName VARCHAR(255);" ,dbFailOnError
```

Change YourTableName  to Your Table Name  and so on.

Execute this line for each field you need to change.

Comment: Good idea, however, I have two issues here:
1. There are 200k+ records per column so when importing I'm getting data error and job can't be completed as I'm running out of resources.
2. Changing data type after it's importing will not help, as it has ignored alphanumeric data

Comment: Sorry but your response is  not clear. the first issue the code is run after the import so  out of resources ?. the second issue I do not know the type of field to which you are converting, but if converted to a 255-character warcher then nothing should be lost. Unless the field is larger than 255 characters

Comment: I just remembered, regarding the first issue, it might be better to use the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet command
Which is more efficient and can be used on CSV files. how to > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet